# How does the event chaining works for multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I'm performing a deleting action on a page when the user click on the confirmation button on a twitter bootstrap modal window button.

I have two buttons: one allow the user to cancel the action, and another one to confirm.

When the user clicks on the confirm delete button, when the modal is hidden, I perform my actions, so for example I can show an animation and actually delete the item.

If the user click on few items but his/her choice is the cancel button, when he/she clicks on the item he/she want to delete, the deletion is performed also on the elements where the choice has been to cancel.

Should not the 'hidden' event be detached from the element once it is performed?

I know I can detach the event chaining changing `$('#confirmDeleteModal').on('hidden', function() {` to `$('#confirmDeleteModal').off('hidden').on('hidden', function() {` but I really **would understand why this happen.** Am I missing something?

The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').on('click', function() {
        var itemID = $(this).data('product-id')

        $('#confirmDeleteModal').modal('show');

        $('#confirmDelete').on('click', function() {

            $('#confirmDeleteModal').on('hidden', function() {
                // Here I do my stuff to perform deletion
                $('#result').append('This method has been called for ' + itemID + ' <br />' )
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I hope I have exposed clearly my question. I prepared a JS Bin as well: http://jsbin.com/inulaw/5/edit

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but yes, you should be detaching the events, or at least not nesting the event attachments like that.

Comment: I would like to know why this happen: once the 'hidden' event has been completed, why is it triggered again? Since you say I should not nest the events like that, there is any better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are attaching ***additional*** listeners to the `click` and `hidden` events each time. To fix this, chain the jQuery `.off('eventName')` method before calling the `.on('eventname')` again.

Here's your code updated and working great in the JS Bin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').on('click', function() {
        var itemID = $(this).data('product-id')

        $('#confirmDeleteModal').modal('show');

        $('#confirmDeleteModal').off('hidden'); // must reset from previous
        $('#confirmDelete').off('click').on('click', function() {

            $('#confirmDeleteModal').on('hidden', function() {

                    // Here I do my stuff to perform deletion
                    $('#result').append('This method has been called for ' + itemID + ' <br />' )
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** I moved the `$('#confirmDeleteModal').off('hidden');` to above the click event so it resets whether or not the confirm is clicked.

Comment: I have tried it and looks like it's not working. I still get the same behavior. I think it's because since when you detach the `hidden` event, the event itself hasn't been queued yet.

Comment: Hmmm... check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mike_marcacci/jCwdN/) I made. Is this not working how you intend?

Comment: I see.. I missed the off('click') on the button itself. That's wierd as well... since I press that button only once, how can it have other events attached?

Comment: When the dialog window closes, it doesn't actually remove the dialog or button; it just hides them. Therefore, when you attach another event handle, you're attaching it to the same button. Glad it worked!